# Is this solution on series convergence correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to calculate the sum of the following series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2^n+(-1)^n)^2}{11^n}$$

My solution.

1) First of all $(2^n + (-1)^n)^2=2^{2n}+2^{n+1}(-1)^n+1$.

2) Then the original series becomes:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2^n+(-1)^n)^2}{11^n}=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{2n}}{11^n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{n+1}(-1)^n}{11^n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{11^n}$$

3) Then I want to apply formula for the sum of geometric series.

4) Finally, I simply want to add three sums.

Is this a correct way to go?

Comment: Yes, your approach is perfect.

Comment: Yes, it is okay to me.

Comment: Looks fine. I would add step 2.5) manipulate the expression so that geometric series is visible but this was a minor addition

Answer (score 1):

Looks Fine. Then use the following conclusion $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n =\frac{1}{1-x}$ if $x\in (-1,1)$